# WebStorm Node.js TypeScript Express debug stuck on connecting to localhost

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, debugging, webstorm

I'm trying to debug my TypeScript Express app using WebStorm.

I have this debug script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk=9229 --require ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register server.ts"
}
```

I run `npm run debug` in the command line and the following loads

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/<somerandomid>
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Now I am able to debug from Chrome inspector by going to Chrome, type in `chrome://inspect/` and `server.ts` would appear in Remote Target, and I can debug the TypeScript by clicking inspect. Hence I know that the problem is not my node.js configuration side.

The problem is, I can't debug when using WebStorm.

I tried the following WebStorm debug configuration:

```
Attach to Node.js/Chrome
Host: localhost
Port: 9229
Attach to: Chrome or Node.js > 6.3 started with --inspect
```

but when I debug in WebStorm the debugger keeps on saying `"Connecting to localhost:9229"` and nothing happens. It doesn't go to breakpoints even though I have set breakpoints in server.ts etc

I tried disabling firewall, still doesn't work. Tried using `--inspect` instead of `--inspect-brk`, still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get WebStorm to debug into breakpoints using my node.js Express TypeScript configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me using your way to start the app/attach the debugger. What WebStorm version do you use?
here are 2 other ways to debug your app:

- using **Node.js** run configuration (create similar configuration and press **Debug**):

[image]

- using **NPM** run configuration:

  1. change your script to `"debug": "node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% --require ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register server.ts"` (if you are on Linux/Mac OSX, replace `%NODE_DEBUG_OPTION%` with `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION`
  2. click the arrow in the gutter, choose **Debug**

[image]